# Best practices for securely using Google API keys in browser extensions

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Google wrote an article about protecting `API KEY` ([LINK](https://developers.google.com/console/help/new/#apikeybestpractices)), but they don't even mention a word about javascript. How do I `safely` use `Google API` (`JavaScript` version) in for example `Chrome Extension`?

Comment: Would you `mind` removing `obnoxious` formatting? Use `*` and `**` to delimit what you need highlighted, if necessary.

Comment: Actually, this one is better: [Secure handling of OAuth Consumer Key and Secret in Chrome Extensions and Gmail Gadgets](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9187894/secure-handling-of-oauth-consumer-key-and-secret-in-chrome-extensions-and-gmail)